# Cannot verify static method in Unit Test using MockedStatic or PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I am really fed up with by trying tens of different approaches to test a static method properly using `MockedStatic` or `PowerMockito` for several days.

I have the following service methods and test method as a unit test for this service method. I cannot verify the static method call when I just call the service method from test method. on the other hand, if I call the service method or the static method in the try block of the test method, it seems to work, but actually it does not. because it just verify the static method call in the try block. if I call the same static method twice, it verify 2 times call. But in reality, it just ht one time to the static method in the service.

So, how can I verify the static method call using `MockedStatic` or `PowerMockito`? Any help would be appreciated.

***service:***

```
// servis method
public CommandDTO create(final EmployeeRequest request) {
    // code omitted

    calculate(); // --> I call this method

    return CommandDTO.builder().uuid(empoyee.getUuid()).build();
}


// private method that calls static method
private void calculate() {
    
    // code omitted

    LoggingUtils.error("Error...");
}
```

***unit test:***

```
@Test
public void test() {

    // code omitted 

    // call service method
    employeeService.create(request);


    try(MockedStatic<LoggingUtils> mocked = Mockito.mockStatic(LoggingUtils.class)) {
        mocked.when(() -> LoggingUtils.error(any()))
            .thenAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> null);

       
        /* ??? I am not sure if I need to call the service method for the 2nd time. 
         * But in any case, I should not call it from here again */
        employeeService.create(request); 

        /* ??? in most examples, the sttaic method is called here. however, it is 
         * meaningless, because if I call 2 times and use times(2) in the following 
         * line, it works. but not called 2 times actually in the service method */
        LoggingUtils.error(any());

        // verify
        mocked.verify(times(1), () -> LoggingUtils.error(any()));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `dummy`?

Comment: @Francesco SOrry, it is `mocked`, I corrected it.

Comment: It gives "*incompatible parameter types in lambda expression: wrong number of parameters: expected 1 but found 0*" for the first paranthesis. Any idea?

Comment: @Francesco Amigo? Where did you go?

Comment: Which version of Mockito you're using? I am on 3.7.7. Well it sounds correct to me that static method is hit twice, I think you say static method is hit once while debbugging because of first `employeeService.create`. Static method is hit one time, as you see, mock is hit two times because of code in the `try .. catch` statement and verify relies on mock.

Comment: The usage of verify is ok for me and it depends on version, your usage (replacing parameters) also ok. The problem is related to the other parts. So, how should I update my code in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is ok, maybe your are confusing mock with static method. Static method is hit once because of `employeeService.create(request);` on top of your test. What is verified twice in you code is not the static method but the mock, the two calls occur in the `try.. catch` block. Doublechecking the stacktrace while debugging should confirm.

By debbugging this code:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    // code omitted

    try (MockedStatic<LoggingUtils> mocked = Mockito.mockStatic(LoggingUtils.class)) {
        mocked.when(() -> LoggingUtils.error(any()))
                .thenAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> null);
        employeeService.create(new Object());
        mocked.verify(times(1), () -> LoggingUtils.error(any()));
    }
}
```

you should see no stop on the static method and test should end fine because mock is called only once in the `try.. catch`.

Comment: Could you please post the code that I should follow by using mu code? I think I do not need to call `employeeService.create(request); ` and `LoggingUtils.error(any());` both in my test method?

Comment: added code to clarify the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but this approach still gives the same error : "Wanted but not invoked:
LoggingUtils.class.error(<any>);" when I use `employeeService.create(request); ` outside of the try or not. Any idea?

Comment: Don't do that, `MockedStatic` mocks work only into the `try.. catch` statement, see the docs: 
https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.7.7/org/mockito/MockedStatic.html

Comment: I also tried what you suggested but still the same error. So, shall I use PowerMock if it is better to use?